# .net server control performance compromise

Tags: asp.net, ajax, performance, postback

We are finding that for a large sets of data server controls (with the amount of postbacks) they do often times result in a very slow performance. 
While we don't want to do all the business logic in Javascript, we would like to speed things up.

What were your solutions/ideas? AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

Two easiest places in ASP.NET to start and get the biggest gains:

- **Reduce ViewState**. The ViewState can very quickly become unwieldy and even plain massive. I've seen developers inadvertently create pages that push down 20mb+ of ViewState. Every communication between client and server has to transmit that data. [Here is a great roundup](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000415.html) on how-tos for using the ViewState in a smart way.
- **Use the [HttpRuntime cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx)**. Once you fetch your data from wherever you're getting it (SQL or whatnot), store it in the cache. Always check the cache for the data before attempting to re-fetch it from the original source. The HttpRuntime cache is *extremely* fast.

  The cache link above has some good basic examples on how to add and remove items with the cache.

Comment: Thanks! I was more concerned with web server - client trips rather than database trips.
Once I fetch the data I can store it in the server object/ session or whatever. My questions is more to do with the ViewState I think. For example, when GridView posts back, this might create slow performance.